# Cakephp onKeyUp

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, cakephp-3.0

Hi this is a very simple and fast question. I have a textbox

```
<?= 
$this->Form->input('contract_prices.'.$num.'.quantity', [
'id' => 'contract-prices-'.$num.'-quantity', 
'name' => 'contract_prices['.$num.'][quantity]',
'label' => false']); 
?>
```

Now i need this textbox whenever a user types on it a javascript/jquery will fire. I just can't find anywhere how to do it. I've tried using `'onkeyup' => 'thisFunction()'` but it's not working. It's just console.log('test'); inside the function for now. Any idea how to make this work? Jquery, Angular, Javascript, any of the three would help me. Whichever works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like this might get you started.  Can't test it sorry, no appropriate environment on this machine.

```
$this->Html->scriptBlock('$(document).on("keyup", "#contract-prices-'.$num.'-quantity", (event) => console.log(event) );', ['block' => true]);
```

You will need to output the script block where appropriate.